# Sending @reply in curl

Tags: php, curl, file-upload

I'm writing an identi.ca client, and seems that @reply isn't working.

After investigation I found that @ prefix is used by curl to indicate file upload, and escaping with \@reply doesn't work; curl doesn't remove the \ at the front.

I also can't format the postfields to query string, as I need to send files on that request too.

Is there any method to send both @reply and file upload in the same request?

Comment: Can you elaborate / show us some code?

Comment: This is a cURL quirk. "--data @filename" causes cURL to post the contents of filename while "--form foo@bar" causes cURL to send the contents of bar as the form value of foo. curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried \@ or urlencode("@reply") but it doesn't seems to work.

Finally, I found that adding a space into the front of the message works. status.net also chop extra space off automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use %40 instead of @